# Excel 2007 rows limit for Excel 2003 macros

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I understand that Excel 2003 has 65,536 rows limitation which was increased to 1,048,576 in Excel 2007.

My question is : If a macro targets Excel 2003, and is opened in Excel 2007, does the 65,536 rows limit still apply?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you're working inside 2007 the limit that will apply is 1,048,576 rows.

See this for an example of what can break your party:

http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming/649719-problem-excel-2003-row-limit-65k-affecting-my-excel2007-macros.html

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for the reply.

So do you mean that converting/saving the excel 2003 spreadsheet containing macro into excel 2007 .xlsm spreadsheet will work fine. And I will not encounter any more row limit issue as seen in excel 2003 (row limit <65k) if I do not have any explicit check for row count in my macro?

Please let me know.

Regards.