# DBNETLIB errors

Tags: sql, excel

What should be a very very straight forward query is giving me trouble.

First, here's the code:

```
`SELECT AcctHist.Acct, AcctHist.CpnyID, AcctHist.FiscYr, AcctHist.LedgerID, AcctHist.PtdBal04 as Curr_Month, sum(AcctHist.PtdBal00+AcctHist.PtdBal01+AcctHist.PtdBal02+AcctHist.PtdBal03+AcctHist.PtdBal04) as YTD_Bal

FROM FFNEApp.dbo.AcctHist AcctHist

WHERE (AcctHist.Acct>='4000000' and AcctHist.LedgerID in ('ACTUAL','STAT','BUDGET','BUDSTAT') and AcctHist.FiscYr in ('2014','2015') and AcctHist.CpnyID not in ('999'))

GROUP BY AcctHist.Acct, AcctHist.CpnyID, AcctHist.FiscYr, AcctHist.LedgerID, AcctHist.PtdBal04`
```

When I refresh the query via my connection in MS Excel, I get three errors.

First is [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionWite (send()).

Next is [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]General network error. Check your network documentation.

Last is Problems obtaining data.

Oddly, when I remove 'BUDGET' from the where clause, it works.  So what would cause the query to fail?  Could a particular record with a LedgerID of BUDGET cause it to hang up?  If so, what's the best way to figure out which record?

Comment: Run the query using SSMS and see how many records have 'budget' in the field in question.

Comment: I had our business systems guy run the same query, except only returning records with the BUDGET ledgerID and it returned 24,138 records.  This would be in addition to the 48,401 records I get when I run the query on the other 3 ledgerID's of ACTUAL, STAT, and BUDSTAT

Comment: Excel 2003 has a 65,536 rows limitation, hopefully that is not the issue. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463992/excel-2007-rows-limit-for-excel-2003-macros

Comment: Shouldn't be.  I am working in excel 2013.